# Tiled Software for Map Creating: Make Tiles out of a entire map

Tags: ios, swift3, tiled

Can you drag an image and have tiled create map and brake the image into small tiles for you. I don't know if it's possible. Like I have image done for my game and I have it in .png file which about 2680 * 1080 and I want to create that image in tile based so i can do A* Pathfinding algorithm.

or if you guys know any other alternative way to do it then please advice me on it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That is how Spritesheets work. Those are big images containing several small tiles.
When adding a new Tileset in Tiled, you choose your image and define the tile-size. Tiled will automatically use them correctly